# How to persist checkbox checked state in Acumatica PXGrid?

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

I have "selected" checkbox column in PXGrid, when i checked it then page postback and checked state does not lost, But when i click on Custom Action button then checked checkbox, unchecked, what should i do to persist checkbox state?

In Action button click, I am opening a Dialogbox, here all checkbox unchecked, PrimaryView and dialogbox data-member are different.

what should i do to persist checkbox state?

Comment: Have you set "commit changes" on the field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yourviewname.Cache.Persist(PXDBOperation.Update);

Answer (score 1):

The `Selected` identifier has a special meaning in processing screens. Acumatica framework applies different behaviors to fields which are named `Selected`. For processing screen it is required to have a field named `Selected`. Outside this scenario you should avoid naming fields `Selected`.

Make sure field is decorated with `PXDBBool` attribute instead of `PXBool` attribute. Only fields with `PXDB` prefix are persisted to database.

Change the field name in database and in the DAC from `Selected` to something else like `IsChecked`.

```
public abstract class isChecked : PX.Data.BQL.BqlBool.Field<isChecked> { }

[PXDBBool]
[PXUIField(DisplayName="Selected")]
public virtual Boolean? IsChecked
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, I got my answer. I have another issue, In processing screen, In which event i can get selected rows on click of Process/Process All button click?

Comment: You can read the value of Selected column only in the Process Delegate method. If you read it elsewhere the value will be invalid. Also you can't set it's value. It's one of the special case associated only with Selected column. The specific method is the one passed in parameter in SetProcessDelegate method. In this documentation page example, it is the "public static void Process(List<ARPaymentInfo> products)" method : https://help-2020r1.acumatica.com/Help?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=b8e279d0-fc1b-7a7a-3ed1-2d585a757e29

Comment: If you can't locate the Process Delegate method, please add your graph source code to your question.

Comment: Thanks for reply, My handler is no-static, and i want to show a popup on click handler and what happen when i click on Process then it select all checkbox automatically while i selected 2, DO know why?
Also how may i get only selected?

Comment: You should make it static because you won't be able to reliably refer to 'this' object in the context of the processing delegate. You can't display a dialog from that method either. It sounds like your not following the processing screen pattern properly, did you call SetProcessDelegate?

Comment: When you click on Process the framework sets the value of Selected column to reflect what the user selected on screen. With Process All it sets all records Selected field to true. If you attempt to read the Selected column outside the process delegate you get invalid values so that should be avoided.

Comment: Yes, I am calling SetProcessDelegate and i made handler static but on click Process, it is still giving me all records. Do you know why?
And also it clear all record after calling static method, Any suggestion why?

Comment: It's normal behavior, do a for each loop on all records and process only the one that have Selected=True

Comment: I am getting all Selected as True, What should i do to show all record in Grid after process end?

Comment: You need to do everything right for processing pattern to work successfully. Your feedback tells me you didn't but I can't help you if you don't post your complete code, there's just too many error you could have done, I can't guess it I need to see your complete code.

Comment: You can refer to this answer to implement the processing delegate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48429034/7376238

Comment: Please check code. 
#region Construtor
        public OrderStatusChangeProcess() {
            OrderSampling.SetProcessDelegate(processOrder);
            OrderSampling.SetSelected<Order.selected>();
        }
        protected static void processOrder(List<Order> listProcessOrder) {
           // Getting all selected as true in listPrecoessOrder
        }
        #endregion Construtor
        #region Dac
        public PXProcessingJoin<Order,
            InnerJoin<Detail, On<Detail.OrderID, Equal<Order.OrderID>>>> Order;
        #endregion

Comment: I am using PXProsessingJoin, Is it the problem?

Comment: No PXProcessingJoin is not a problem. We need the complete solution to troubleshoot your issue though, I can't work from that code snippet in comments. Based on only that it just seems like the implementation is incomplete. You really need to get everything right otherwise it just won't work and there's not enough code in what you posted for it to work properly.

Comment: Please check in link. I have modified the Actual code variable name to show you othwise all are same. 
https://repl.it/repls/AstonishingInferiorCubase

Comment: I think that wouldn't compile, the call for SetProcessDelegate is using parameter processQCOrder but the process delegate method has another name processOrder

Comment: Besides that the process delegate is empty, that could explain why the records disappear after process. There needs to be some code in the process delegate like explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48429034/7376238

Comment: Thanks, that i did, Only one issue left, which is row selected. May you tell me why?
Also i changed the deletegate name.

Comment: I am doing same as they suggested, but after closing the process dialog, Grid blank. Also i am still getting all rows selected, May you suggest any answer?

Comment: Thanks for All your help, I solved all issues, Just grid is disappering after process selected records. 
I have one more question: If my processing join with multiple tables, and i want to get all the records with their join table entity in ProcessDelegate method, How may i get it?

I have to process records by multiplekey, that's-why i need join enity also in process delegate.

Comment: Call SetInfo on the records processed successfully in the process delegate. That should help them stay in grid, they should have a green checkmark after being processed. It's generally good that they disappear after refresh if your business rule is to process them once which is often the case. PXProcessing<POLandedCostDoc>.SetInfo(row, PX.Data.ActionsMessages.RecordProcessed);

Comment: Typically processing view is to process a single type of record. They are very limited and hard to setup. I didn't find example on getting other DAC from query so I think you have to reselect them. You should also crate a new graph in process delegate to handle record, something like OrderMaint. It's hard to tell exactly because your implementation is incomplete. Detail detail = PXSelect<Detail, Where<Detail.orderID, Equal<Required<Detail.OrderID>>>>.Select(new PXGraph(), order.OrderID);

Comment: Thanks @Hugues sir for continues support, My all queries are solved. I was just thinking to keep grid records stay after processing the records. But as you said, Business rules said to keep processed records in Grid, So user can see their processed records(either red/green color), after that user need to refresh to see all other records.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Hugues sir, I am facing another issue in Processing diffrent screen, I want to pass a graph Global value to static process delegate, How may i do that?

I have parent and child relationship data, and i am updating child data and calling graph save method then getting error like ParentId can not be empty, I set the parent entity in graph for ex:  
ParentOrderDAC
ChildOrderDAC

OrderDACGraph
i set OrderPrimaryView.Current = ParentOrderDACEnity
then call ChildOrderDAC.Name = 'A';
ChildOrderDAC.Update(ChildOrderDAC);
call OrderDACGraph.save(); getting parentOrderID empty error, why?